# SQL: How to get courses that are both in undergrad and postgrad degree?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Data:

```
Programs  
- degree (name)  
- Course (course list)  

Degrees  
- code (unique identifier)  
- name  
- type (either postgrad or undergrad)  

Course  
- code (unique identifier)   
- name
```

So, some courses are present in both `undergrad` and `postgrad` degrees and I would like to know how to get all of those courses.

Comment: Please add some sample data to your question for all three tables.

Comment: And to add on to @TimBiegeleisen's comment. Please show how your desired output should look like, it will help us help you model the query better. 
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is aggregation:

```
select p.course
from program p inner join
     degrees d
     on d.Code = p.Degree
where d.type in ('postgrad', 'undergrad')
group by p.course
having count(distinct d.type) = 2;
```

You only need to join in `course` if you need the name rather than the code.

Comment: oh yeah, I think this is right, or at least it printed out the expected amount of rows, thanks!
If it's not too much trouble, can you give any guidance toward doing the follow-up to this probelem? I added it to the main post, thanks, I appreciate all the help!

Comment: @AnonLi . . . New questions should be asked as *new* questions, not as edits to already answered ones.

Answer (score 0):

This should assist you with your requirement,

```
SELECT C.Name
from
Program P
inner join Degrees D
on D.Code=P.Degree and (D.Type = 'postgrad' OR D.Type = 'undergrad')
inner join Course C
on C.Code=P.Course
group by C.Name
having count(*)>1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment! I'm going to verify the output, but at least it output something as opposed to what I had before haha

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't. I got 50 rows as output when the expected should be 19 rows

Comment: Can you try now

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with 2 subselects like this:

```
SELECT c.name
from course C 
-- at least one postgrad programs/degrees for this course
inner join (
    select distinct p.course 
    from Program P inner join Degrees D on d_pg.Code=P.Degree 
    where D.Type = 'postgrad'
) as P_pg on C.Code=P_pg.Course
-- at least one undergrad programs/degrees for this course
inner join (
    select distinct p.course 
    from Program P inner join Degrees D on d_pg.Code=P.Degree 
    where D.Type = 'undergrad'
) as P_ug on C.Code=P_ug.Course
where 1=1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an intersection:

```
select courses.name
from courses
inner join programs on programs.course = courses.name
inner join degrees on degrees.code = programs.degree
where degrees.type = 'UG'
intersect
select courses.name
from courses
inner join programs on programs.course = courses.name
inner join degrees on degrees.code = programs.degree
where degrees.type = 'PG';
```

The query goes as follows: Select all of the courses which are undergraduate, and intersect the result with the postgraduate courses.

If you want the undergrad courses only, you can use `except` instead of intersect (exchange the two queries and use `except` if you want postgrad courses only).